# RAID5 fails while recovering (mdadm): Any chance to resync?

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid, mdadm

My RAID5 is going to die because, while restoring a failed HDD, on another HDD read errors occurred and a restore is impossible. I just want to know whether it's possible to restore only a part of remaining data - most of them should be there anyway.

I don't have a full backup, because 25TB of data are not easy to backup. I know: No Backup - No Mercy. That's okay. But I want to try. I cannot imagine, it's not possible to bring this raid back to life.

My current configuration:

- RAID5 with 5 HDD (WD WD60EFRX Red SA3), 6TB
- OS is on extra SSD
- Ubuntu 16.04 with a mdadm software raid

One day, `/dev/sda` failed with following message:

```
This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm running on ***

A Fail event had been detected on md device /dev/md/0.

It could be related to component device /dev/sda1.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0 [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid5 sde1[5] sdb1[1] sda1[0](F) sdc1[7] sdd1[6]
23441545216 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/4] [_UUUU]
bitmap: 4/44 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

So I did the following:

Checked the disk:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-93-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD60EFRX-68MYMN1
Serial Number:    WD-WX41D75LN5CP
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2620bfa28
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    6.001.175.126.016 bytes [6,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5700 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Jan 30 22:02:37 2018 CET
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        ( 7004) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 723) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x303d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   001   001   051    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 37802
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   217   189   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       8141
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   077   077   000    Old_age   Always       -       17248
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   194   194   000    Old_age   Always       -       19683
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   113   103   000    Old_age   Always       -       39
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Checked the raid:

```
$ sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0
    /dev/md0:
            Version : 1.2
      Creation Time : Tue Dec 15 22:20:33 2015
         Raid Level : raid5
         Array Size : 23441545216 (22355.60 GiB 24004.14 GB)
      Used Dev Size : 5860386304 (5588.90 GiB 6001.04 GB)
       Raid Devices : 5
      Total Devices : 5
        Persistence : Superblock is persistent

      Intent Bitmap : Internal

        Update Time : Tue Jan 30 22:07:30 2018
              State : clean
     Active Devices : 5
    Working Devices : 5
     Failed Devices : 0
      Spare Devices : 0

             Layout : left-symmetric
         Chunk Size : 512K

               Name : fractal.hostname:0  (local to host fractal.hostname)
               UUID : e9bdcf76:c5e04a88:32d5dfa6:557bdeaf
             Events : 80222

        Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
           0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
           1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
           7       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
           6       8       49        3      active sync   /dev/sdd1
           5       8       65        4      active sync   /dev/sde1
    #  cat /proc/mdstat
    Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
    md0 : active raid5 sde1[5] sdb1[1] sda1[0] sdc1[7] sdd1[6]
          23441545216 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/5] [UUUUU]
          bitmap: 4/44 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

    unused devices: <none>
```

So the drive was not failed now, but going to.
So I removed it from raid,

```
# mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1
mdadm: set /dev/sda1 faulty in /dev/md0

# mdadm /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda1
mdadm: hot removed /dev/sda1 from /dev/md0
```

rebooted, and added the new one after copying the partition tables:

```
sgdisk --backup=gpt_backup /dev/sdb
sgdisk --load-backup=gpt_backup /dev/sda
sgdisk -G /dev/sda

mdadm --manage /dev/md0 -a /dev/sda1
```

While recovering, another drive (`/dev/sdb`) failed as follows:

```
This is an automatically generated mail message from mdadm
running on fractal.hostname

A Fail event had been detected on md device /dev/md/0.

It could be related to component device /dev/sdb1.

Faithfully yours, etc.

P.S. The /proc/mdstat file currently contains the following:

Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid5 sda1[8] sdb1[1](F) sde1[5] sdc1[7] sdd1[6]
     23441545216 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [5/3] [__UUU]
     [===================>.]  recovery = 99.5% (5835184192/5860386304) finish=595.0min speed=703K/sec
     bitmap: 0/44 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

He obviously could not read some sectore for restore:

```
This message was generated by the smartd daemon running on:

  host name:  fractal
  DNS domain: hostname

The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:

Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 167 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors

Device info:
WDC WD60EFRX-68MYMN1, S/N:WD-WX41D75LN3YP, WWN:5-0014ee-20cb6e76b, FW:82.00A82, 6.00 TB

For details see host's SYSLOG.

You can also use the smartctl utility for further investigation.
The original message about this issue was sent at Wed Jan 31 14:15:20 2018 CET
Another message will be sent in 24 hours if the problem persists.
```

I tried the same procedure three times and everytime it failed the same way (only when reached another progress, sometimes 60%, sometimes 99,5%).

After several tries, I reassambled the array but it ended the same way:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : inactive sdb1[1](S) sde1[5](S) sdc1[7](S) sdd1[6](S) sda1[8](S)
      29301944199 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
# mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : fractal.hostname:0  (local to host fractal.hostname)
           UUID : e9bdcf76:c5e04a88:32d5dfa6:557bdeaf
         Events : 133218

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8        1        -        /dev/sda1
       -       8       17        -        /dev/sdb1
       -       8       33        -        /dev/sdc1
       -       8       49        -        /dev/sdd1
       -       8       65        -        /dev/sde1
# mdadm --assemble --update=resync --force /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
mdadm: forcing event count in /dev/sdb1(1) from 132262 upto 133218
mdadm: clearing FAULTY flag for device 0 in /dev/md0 for /dev/sda1
mdadm: Marking array /dev/md0 as 'clean'
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md0: Input/output error
# mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : fractal.hostname:0  (local to host fractal.hostname)
           UUID : e9bdcf76:c5e04a88:32d5dfa6:557bdeaf
         Events : 133218

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       49        -        /dev/sdd1
       -       8       65        -        /dev/sde1
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : inactive sde1[5](S) sdd1[6](S)
      11720776864 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
# mdadm --assemble --update=resync --force /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: /dev/sde1 is busy - skipping
mdadm: Merging with already-assembled /dev/md/0
mdadm: Marking array /dev/md/0 as 'clean'
mdadm: /dev/md/0 has been started with 4 drives (out of 5) and 1 spare.
# mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Tue Dec 15 22:20:33 2015
     Raid Level : raid5
     Array Size : 23441545216 (22355.60 GiB 24004.14 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 5860386304 (5588.90 GiB 6001.04 GB)
   Raid Devices : 5
  Total Devices : 5
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Sat Feb 10 09:42:03 2018
          State : clean, degraded, recovering
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 5
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

 Rebuild Status : 0% complete

           Name : fractal.hostname:0  (local to host fractal.hostname)
           UUID : e9bdcf76:c5e04a88:32d5dfa6:557bdeaf
         Events : 133220

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       8       8        1        0      spare rebuilding   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       7       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       6       8       49        3      active sync   /dev/sdd1
       5       8       65        4      active sync   /dev/sde1
```

Do you see any chance to recover my data without loss? Is there any possibility to recover a part of my data? Obviously, he could sync until 99,5% but I could not use it.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your drives have a 1/10^14 read error rate according to specs, if you use the formula from https://serverfault.com/questions/591777/what-counts-as-a-large-raid-5-array that gives you a 21.9% chance of rebuild failure. For brand new working drives that is.

Comment: If you really want to try to recover your data you need to stop using and modifying these drives. So 30TB to backup the raw content of the drives and another 24TB where you will re-assemble the data.

Comment: So - in case of I recover my data - what modification to my raid would you suggest? Switch to RAID6?

Comment: I wouldn't use RAID 5 or 6. Do the math, but if I'm not wrong you get a chance of rebuild failure of 16.9% with 5 drives in RAID 6 (so less usable space) and still 21.9% if you add a drive to make it 6 drives in RAID 6.